# IAudioClient cuts the beginning of sounds

Tags: c++, windows, audio, audio-streaming

If I try to play a sound using `IAudioClient` I get the sound cut in the beginning. However, if I add a delay after `Start` is called and actual data is loaded into the buffer, everything works fine. I understand the device needs some time to be initialized but there's no way to know when exactly it's ready.

Is there any way to know that the audio engine is fully initialized and all the data will be played without cutting? Is there any solution to this situation? I tried to create some unused device during application startup and keep it playing (nothing) so that all subsequently created device works from the start and it worked, but is there any other (correct)

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

hr = CoInitialize(nullptr);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

IMMDeviceEnumerator* deviceEnumerator = nullptr;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&deviceEnumerator);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

IMMDevice* device = nullptr;
hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &device);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

IAudioClient* audioClient = nullptr;
hr = device->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_ALL, nullptr, (void**)&audioClient);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

WAVEFORMATEX* waveFormat = nullptr;
hr = audioClient->GetMixFormat(&waveFormat);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

const REFERENCE_TIME requestedDuration = ReftimesPerSecond;
hr = audioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 0, requestedDuration, 0, waveFormat, nullptr);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

AudioSource audioSource;
hr = audioSource.Read("../short1.wav", *waveFormat);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

// Get the actual size of the allocated buffer.
UINT32 bufferFrameCount = 0;
hr = audioClient->GetBufferSize(&bufferFrameCount);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

IAudioRenderClient* renderClient = nullptr;
hr = audioClient->GetService(__uuidof(IAudioRenderClient), (void**)&renderClient);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

// Start playing.
hr = audioClient->Start();
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

// If uncomment everything works.
//Sleep(500);

// Calculate the actual duration of the allocated buffer.
const REFERENCE_TIME actualDuration = ReftimesPerSecond * bufferFrameCount / waveFormat->nSamplesPerSec;
const REFERENCE_TIME halfActualDurationInMilliseconds = actualDuration / ReftimesPerMillisecond / 2;

DWORD flags = 0;

// Each loop fills about half of the shared buffer.
do
{
    // See how much buffer space is available.
    UINT32 paddingFrameCount = 0;
    hr = audioClient->GetCurrentPadding(&paddingFrameCount);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    const UINT32 availableFrameCount = bufferFrameCount - paddingFrameCount;

    // Grab all the available space in the shared buffer.
    BYTE* data = nullptr;
    hr = renderClient->GetBuffer(availableFrameCount, &data);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    // Get next 1/2-second of data from the audio source.
    hr = audioSource.LoadData(availableFrameCount, data, &flags, *waveFormat);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    hr = renderClient->ReleaseBuffer(availableFrameCount, flags);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    // Sleep for half the buffer duration.
    Sleep((DWORD)halfActualDurationInMilliseconds);
} while (flags != AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT);

// Wait for last data in buffer to play before stopping.
Sleep((DWORD)halfActualDurationInMilliseconds);

// Stop playing.
hr = audioClient->Stop();
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the IAudioClient2 which has a GetBufferSizeLimit Method inside:
[IAudioClient2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudioclient2-getbuffersizelimits)